# AWS CLI - sam deploy vs sam sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

What is the difference between AWS `sam deploy` and `sam sync` and when should I use which one?

Comment: Please read [ask]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sam deploy**

The `sam deploy` command simply deploys your serverless application to the cloud. Use it to manually deploy the application.

**sam sync**

The `sam sync` command provides options to quickly sync local application changes to the AWS Cloud. Use it to automate the deployment as you make changes in your development environment.

Use sam sync when developing your applications to:

1. Automatically detect and sync local changes to the AWS Cloud.
2. Customize what local changes are synced to the AWS Cloud.
3. Prepare your application in the cloud for testing and validation.

With `sam sync`, you can create a rapid development workflow that shortens the time it takes to sync your local changes to the cloud for testing and validation.

It does the following:

1. Build your application – This process is similar to using the `sam build` command.
2. Deploy your application – The SAM CLI deploys your application to AWS CloudFormation using your default settings. This process is similar to using the `sam deploy` command.
3. Watch for local changes – The SAM CLI remains running and watches for local changes to your application. This is what the --watch option provides.
4. Sync local changes to the AWS Cloud – When you make local changes, the SAM CLI detects and syncs those changes to the AWS Cloud through the quickest method available.

**Note:** Since the `sam sync` command automatically updates your application in the AWS Cloud, it is recommended for development environments only.

Source: [AWS Documentation - Using sam sync](https://app.bitly.com/Bd3hgZxoeRa/bitlinks/3QuhtBJ/details)

Comment: Does that mean that I should use sam deploy only for the first time I create my infrastructure on AWS (and when I want to create new resource) and every other time to use sam sync?